# Tracking traffic with Mobile App tracking

Tags: facebook, tracking

Good day!

We use [Mobileapptraking](http://www.mobileapptracking.com/) to collect statistics. For marketing purposes, we would like to use their links. Can you suggest how to do it to gather statistics on transitions and install applications for Facebook users. For example, for [this page](https://apps.facebook.com/maya-island/?fb_source=appcenter_request&request_ids=664306913582767).

Best regards, Anton